# Android developer moving to iOS - What do I need to know?

Tags: iphone, android, transition

I'm interested in starting developing on the iOS platform, after a couple of years of Android work. What are the main things that are likely to trip me up when designing/coding for iOS instead of Android?

Comment: the main issue will be  , Objective-C :D

Comment: And the 99$/y thing needed to sell your applications

Comment: Per year?! :-O I thought it was a one off!

Comment: @Saif I'm not so concerned with language barriers, more the structure and features of the iOS SDK, and how that affect the structure of my apps.

Comment: Having to do some comparatively huge workaround because the feature you need implement uses a private API, which Apple have no good reason for not documenting. Also there a few relatively minor inconsistencies that just get annoying *if* you run into one.

Comment: Could be wrong, but you may have to buy a mac :p

Comment: Just costs: $99/year, cost of a mac, and afaik, you only get paid when you have at least $250 to be sent to you. Also the market has a lot more apps.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have done some `iphone` apps after doing Android.

- Objective-c is just another language; not at all hard to learn.
- Understand how iPhone memory works. How the ref count and `AutoreleasePool`s stack works. This should be the most important thing to learn.
- You will love the interface builder. Creating a new screen for the iPhone is much easier.
- iPhone's version of the Android `ListView` is called a `TableView`. More or less the same but you need to define an amount of sections.
- I love how iPhone devs use the Delegate pattern, I am using it in Android now. Pay attention to that.
- Resources can have their own folders. For example: A drawable can be in `/car/model/drawable`
- Adding animation to iphone objects is *VERY* easy. You will notice that a lot of methods have a last parameter with `BOOL animated`.
- Creating custom components is easier.

Things that made me lose a lot of time:

- You can send msgs to `NIL`.
- Logs are not as friendly as Android's.
- You need to add every file to the project. It's not just putting it in the correct place.
- Updates to the env means downloading 2GB every time.
- When printing logs with `NSLog`, `NSString` needs to use `%@` not `%s`.
- Xcode has some strange behavior. The cursor moves around your screen.
- Merging commits in iPhone source is hard. The project file and the xibs always get conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say that Dont use Interface Builder, Try to make application through coding
with this you will easily catch the building process for IPhone program.